# Document viewer uses white fonts in white input fields

Tags: pdf, evince

How can I change this behavior to having black text?

I got a pdf I'd like to fill input fields. However, the font is white on a white background[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpdOx.png). When I select the typed text, one can see it[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PHIP.png).

[image: This is the result after filling the field]
[image: You see? Mark what I just typed.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the same issue myself, in my case it seems to be caused by using a "dark" style/theme in xfce4 ("Adwaita-dark" to be specific).

I *can* see what I'm typing while filling in forms by temporarily switching to inverted colors in Atril (View > Inverted Colors) while filling in forms, or just by switching back to a light style/theme using the "Appearance" settings.

Comment: Indeed, I use a dark system style. And as I see this answer I get that I could have put more details into my question. As a matter of fact, now I cannot reproduce the behavior anymore with the pdf used that time. Maybe there was another evince version that time or otherwise. However, I am sure this would have helped, so accepting. Thank you!

Comment: I just ran into this problem, but changing to a light theme doesn't seem to effect anything.  It also only effects some text entry fields on my pdfs, while others behave normally.  I suspect an evince bug and for now am just using firefox to edit pdfs.

Answer (score 1):

Doing simple tasks makes it show up.

Doing a Ctrl-P for Print, then the Preview button (press or Alt-V), and then canceling out of that makes the text visible normally.  Have to do that for each field.

Or, while in a field doing Ctrl-S to save fixes it.  Works either if you save or cancel with the Esc key.  Also for each field, if you want to see what you have typed.

If you don't care to fiddle to immediately see previous fields, one final saving fixes all.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I wasted half a day trying to solve this problem and finally gave up until now.

Answer (score 0):

**Xournal++** is an open-source and cross-platform note-taking software.

https://xournalpp.github.io/

https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp

Some Xournal++ features:

- Annotate on top of PDFs
- Text tool for adding text in different fonts, colors, and sizes (button [T])
- Export to PDF
- Export to .xopp (Xournal++ file format)

Possible drawback :
Form fields using Xournal++ Text tool are not extractable.